# Default value for \addlinespace from booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs

In the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) package documentation the command is described in the following:

> Occasionally we want to put an extra space between certain rows of a table; for
>   example, before the last row, if this is a total. This is simply a matter of inserting
>   `\addlinespace[width]` after the `\\` alignment marker.

Further the documentation says:

> The default space before or after an adjacent rule is replaced by exactly `\defaultaddspace` or the amount of space speciﬁed in the optional argument.

I, however, do not know how to use this command, for instance

```
\defaultaddspace{10pt}
```

before or inside the tabular environment results in `\defaultaddspace{10pt}`

`Missing number, treated as zero.`

***Followup:***

`\addlinespace` works now, however, I cannot get the desired result:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{0.66\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Title} & \textbf{A}\\
\addlinespace
Row & B\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The borders are broken when I insert `\addlinespace`. The space is added, but in this extra space there are no lined borders on the left and on the right.

Comment: `\defaultaddspace 10pt` works without compilation errors, however no changes are present.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcommand\myVSpace[1][10pt]{\rule[\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|p{0.66\textwidth}|}\hline
\myVSpace\textbf{Title} & \textbf{A}\\[\defaultaddspace]
Row & B\\\hline
\myVSpace[20pt]Row & B\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

or do not use booktabs and then `\\[10pt]` instead.
[image]

The image shows how the optional argument of `\rule` works. 
I used `\rule[...]{10pt}{#1}` to make the box visible

Comment: Sweet, works like a charm. Thank you both of you.

Comment: But where do you put the command if you want the default space right after the \hline? So the space is added before `\textbf{Title} & \textbf{A}` and after it? Because this way only space on bottom of the text is added!

Comment: \\[\defaultaddspace] only adds space after the row. Any idea how extra space is added BEFORE the row?

Comment: @BrokenClockwork: see my edited example

Answer (score 7):

The `\defaultaddspace` is a dimension (=length). You have to set it either with:
`\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{10pt}` (LaTeX) or `\defaultaddspace=10pt` (plainTeX syntax).

The error appears because `\defaultaddspace` looks for a number (or the optional `=` + number) but only finds the `{`.

You would either set it before the table or using `\global\defaultaddspace=10pt`. It will be grouped inside a table sell and the change is lost when `\global` is not used.

Note set `\defaultaddspace` will only be used when `\addlinespace` is used without the optional argument.

Comment: Thanks, but I can add as much pt as I want, there is no difference for my tabular.

Comment: You are using `\addlinespace` as well, do you? Maybe you should post a minimal working example which shows the issue.

Comment: I did not use \addlinespace, I hoped \defaultaddspace adds space at every row automatically, but I guess I have to do it manually, thanks!

Comment: Yes, the name is a little confusing. It is the default value of `\addlinespace` not the default added space. :-)

Comment: Could you take a look at my followup in the original question post, I don't know if it clear what I mean.